# Can I modify the sharepoint error message?

Tags: 2013, error, unique

I have list in which there is a column that is set to store unique values only.

I want to display the user friendly error message when the duplicate value is enetered.

For example, below is image of sharepoint's error message.

[image: enter code here]

I want to alter the text "This value already exists in the list" to something else.

Is that possible? If yes, then how to accomplish this?

Comment: I would be my money that this text is part of one of SharePoint's resource files, make a search inside the .resx files in the Resources folder in the 15-hive.

Answer (score 1):

This particular resource string isn't one of the strings externalized in the RESX files in the 15 HIVE. The only way to really change it would be to create a custom form in InfoPath or in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery in a Script Editor webpart on your NewForm or EditForm pages as follows to change the alert message:

```
<script src="[yoursource]/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span[class=ms-formvalidation]:contains('This value already exists')").text('[Insert whatever message you want here...]');
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I actually haven't yet gotten this to work on the NewForm, but I have on a custom EditForm.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: [Customize Error/Alert Messages on New/Edit/Display Forms](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/182998/customize-error-alert-messages-on-new-edit-display-forms)

Using the SharePoint `PreSaveAction` and a yielded function (when the Form can't be saved)