# Customize Error/Alert Messages on New/Edit/Display Forms

Tags: javascript, error, form

I want to customize the error message for unique values in a list:

> this value already exists in this list.

Tried [Can I modify the sharepoint error message?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82963/can-i-modify-the-sharepoint-error-message)

but it's not working. any working solutions, please?

Answer (score 1):

That String is not available in the Strings Resource object, so you can only get it after it  is displayed in the Browser.

That is possible by using SharePoints own `PreSaveAction` function where you can do your own checking.

This function must return a boolean. A `true` tells SharePoint to go ahead and save the form.

So:

- if you return `true` and SharePoint **can** save the Item, it will be saved.
- if you return `true` and SharePoint **can not** save, the alerts will be displayed
  **IMPORTANT ==> and any declared timeOut function will execute**.

This works for me as a Chrome Snippet:

```
    console.info('set PreSaveAction');
    function PreSaveAction(){//tell SharePoint we check the Form first
        //add a delayed function, 
        _spYield(function(){
        //it will NOT get executed when SP succesfully saved the form and opened another page
            var alerts=document.querySelectorAll("span[role='alert']");
            if(alerts.length===0){
                console.error('Increase yield time. Or something else is wrong')
            }
            console.info( alerts.length+' alerts on this form');
            for(var alertnr=0;alertnr<alerts.length;alertnr++){
                var alert=alerts[ alertnr ];
                console.log( alertnr , alert );
                if( alert.innerHTML.indexOf('This value already exists')>-1){
                    alert.innerHTML='You can not add duplicates!'                    
                }
            }
        },100);//give SP some time to try a save OR display the alerts
        return true;//we say the form is correct, now let SP save it
    }
```

- _spYield is SharePoints own wrapper around the setTimeout function
- Stick it in a Content Editor WebPart, **displayed below** the Form
- No need for bloated jQuery

iForm iJS

Answer (score 0):

Open the newform.aspx in sharepoint designer convert the form to xslt form, where you can change the value if you are xslt expert , otherwise it will be mess up or use the jquery code suggested in your link